# why ternary expression in typescript will change type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to figure out why the type will be changed after the ternary expression.

Take the following code as an example:

```
type CommonProps = {
  entityName: string
  value: string
}

type VeritasFrom = {
  pcsEndpoint: string
  msp: string
}

type personaList = CommonProps[]
type commonList = CommonProps[]
type veritasList = (CommonProps & { from: VeritasFrom[] })[]
type brandedList = (CommonProps & { providers: string })[]
    
function test(list: personaList | commonList | veritasList | brandedList) {
  const output = true ? list : list
  console.log(output) // the type is "personaList" 
}
```

why the `output` type is not `personaList | commonList | veritasList | brandedList` (same as `list`), but `personaList`?

Reproduction [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwXAdgBQE5zAZygXigG8BYAKCighWAEtQA5AQwQgC4odgNaUBzcpQBuTADYBXdp268BZAL7lyoSFABqEHsCY4AYlgQFigqGADGOAKIoAJmDi9gHLj34mEOMM5luFSsirQkBg4qEwAMrRcRvBIqJjYOADaALrK4NBmiMgokdGEsTkJuKnpqkKa9Dp5wEYAFIXxWLhQAGTEUABmBhwaWjr6iKlQ8gCUpQEZUABGGEy2EDY19Y3ozXjtRKZYQrQ2mjjernwj42kUlFD+neIoZnSoUMAQXHWiUU6mB2HLAD5QWTiuQ+UH+FX6OD+MzmCyWH1GxguWRQ0Tg4mAYHRRm4kigAH4oO9ohwicATMjQqIIAA6URwPh1NEY9EIgD0rKeAAtoIEoFEoAAiYKhFARD4Cq4KIA).

I will be grateful if anyone could help!

Comment: Show the definitions of those types too, please.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDclT.png / https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBJBODOB7AdgQwDIEt7CgXih1k2QHMBtAXQG4BYAKFEigGNEBbdlLHfKZAK7sARhFhU6jcNABuYzMFTweuAgG8ARADNEiDQC5CwYmQC+Ehk2jDYqZABMI9lX03DUsA-yGjxlU5IMWgLILMCYKFDAEDgAFAA22MCGcEhoLgA+rBxcyJlQcsSKyklQWTZ2js5JAJRQagxQ2ci8iALAYO18xgLQAPxQibyGQ8CNzUjxEAB08YiksW0d7TUMpkA

Comment: hello @AKX I've updated the post with an reproduction link

Comment: It's possible that's a TypeScript bug. It seems to narrow it to the common compatible type.

Comment: Workaround (semantics not exactly the same since it now allows mixed lists): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwXAdgBQE5zAZygXigG8BYAKCighWAEtQA5AQwQgC4odgNaUBzcpQBuTADYBXdp268BZAL7lyoSFABqEHsCY4AYlgQFigqGADGOAKIoAJmDi9gHLj34mEOMM5luFSsirQGlo6RlAAFPBIqJjYeABkxFAAZgYcwfQ6+ogA2gC6UPIAlMrg0ABCGEy2EDZhkYjI6Fi4UIlEplhCtDaaON6ufIUlZOTJ4ihmdKhQwBBc4aK0XBwAghhVIAA8UU2xrQA+6pqZeEeV1b02AHxFxhRQZqhcUHDiwGDvRtySUAD8UCWLw4QOAJieKBwcFEEAAdKI4Hxwm8Pu8RvIgA

Comment: because `personaList | commonList | veritasList | brandedList` is same as `personaList` or `commonList`.

Comment: how could they be the same? Typescript can inference `VeritasFrom` from the value of `list` type but not from `personaList ` @ABOS

Comment: @LinShen, as far as typescript concerns, all your types are narrowed down to a common type, just think about `string | "a"`  will be narrowed down to `string`. Typescript only cares about assignability.